# Ways to inject services into a component?

Tags: javascript, angular

Currently I am injecting via constructor as shown below, is there any other way to inject service into an component whenever I require rather than injecting on an constructor

```
export class AppService { 
  private users: User[] = []; 
  constructor( private backend: BackendService, private logger: Logger) { } 
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific issue using constructor injection? Have you read the docs pages related to DI (e.g. https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection)?

Comment: You could always use the traditional `new BackendService()` (for example).... but if that service has other dependencies you would have to create them too, and the same with the dependencies of the dependencies, and so on. That's why you should relay on the angular DI. Another way would be to request in the constructor an [`Injector`](https://angular.io/api/core/Injector) and get the dependencies through it, but what's the point then? It's angular anyways giving you the dependencies. In general, try to never do this, and rely on the DI mechanism implemented by Angular (link by @jonrsharpe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can inject the Injector of angular as dependency and use the same to inject our services as dependency whenever required like shown below,

```
import { Injector } from '@angular/core';
export class AppService { 
 private users: User[] = [];
 constructor( private injector: Injector, private logger: Logger) { } 
 someMethod() {

  let backendService: BackEndService = this.injector.get(BackEndService);
  ....

  }
}
```